# image not showing if there is a space between image name in rails with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using carrierwave gem to upload images in rails. But my images are not showing in a slider if there a space between image name. Any help?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, along with "[mcve]". You're asking us to imagine your code and system but our imaginations are not sufficient for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting filename when uploading file:
[Carrierwave doc](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Customize-your-version-file-names)

Override filename method in your uploader:

```
def filename
  original_filename.gsub(/\s+/, '_') if original_filename
end
```

It will change all spaces to underscores.